# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined when firestore would run backups

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to work on 'exporting firestore data' by scheduling once a day. This is [firebase official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export). I tried but it was not working because the error below:

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

The code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const firestoreClient = require('@google-cloud/firestore')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const firestore = admin.firestore()

//------------------------------------------------------
// backup
//------------------------------------------------------
const client = new firestoreClient.v1.FirestoreAdminClient()
exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 24 hours')
  .onRun(() => {
    const databaseName = client.databasePath(
      process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
      '(default)',
    )
    const bucket = 'gs://backups-firestore'
    return client
      .exportDocuments({
        name: databaseName,
        outputUriPrefix: bucket,
        collectionIds: [
          'users',
        ],
      })
      .then((responses) => {
        const response = responses[0]
        console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`)
        return response
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
        throw new Error('Export operation failed')
      })
  })
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when logging the response in the console? Could you please share the response you are getting? This is happening probably because the response is undefined. Could you also verify that .env.GCP_PROJECT is not empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get this error message if `process.env.GCP_PROJECT` is undefined.
`process.env.GCP_PROJECT` is undefined in Node.js 10, while it was working in Node.js 8.

If you do this instead, it should work:

```
const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
const databaseName = client.databasePath(
      projectId,
      '(default)',
    )
```

Comment: Wow... spent the whole day looking through my code and answers online... this solved it for me.